# "Exists" clause in KQL

Tags: sql, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a requirement where I want to use the "exists" clause in the KQL.

Select * from temp A
where exists ( select col1 from temp B where A.col2 = B.col2 and B.col1 < 3)
and A.col3 = 'val3';

I want to translate the above query into Kusto Query Language. I don't see anything like "exists" clause in KQL. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you could try something like this:

```
tableA
| where col3 == 'val3'
| where col2 in ((tableB | where col1 < 3 | project col2))
```

Comment: A and B are the aliases for the same table, they are not different tables. I want to mimic a standard SQL's corelated subquery in KQL.